# How to play background music in KaboomJS

Tags: kaboom

I am making a game with the kaboom library and would like to add background music, i read the docs and found `const music = play("music"); music.loop()` but this seems to only play it once, the file is an MP3 file and i dont get any    errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

`const music = play("music", {loop: true});`

to loop your music.

Answer (score 0):

You can write as following to loop:

```
loadSound("music", "path/to/music.mp3").then((music) =>{
   music.play({loop:true});
});
```